# Use of expandable list view in side menu in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and getting problem in implementation of expandable list in side menu. When I click of option in side menu, the original screen is return and I have to again open side to access the expanded option.

I need the side menu to be there when main option is clicked, so that I can access the expanded option in side menu.

Please help me out and thanks in advance